# EF - requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to create a new table that only has foreign keys:

```
public class OnlyFKs
    {
        public double a3 { get; set; }
        public int a1 { get; set; }
        public int a2 { get; set; }
        public string b { get; set; }
        public Bs B { get; set; }
        public As A { get; set; }
    }
```

Within A & B there exists a:

```
public ICollection<OnlyFKs> OnlyFKs { get; set; }
```

What's going poorly:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OnlyFKs>(o =>
            {
                o.HasOne<Bs>(thisB => thisB.B)
                    .WithMany(g => g.OnlyFKs)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.b);
                o.HasOne<As>(thisA => thisA.A)
                    .WithMany(g => g.OnlyFKs)
                    .HasForeignKey(g => new { g.a1, g.a2, g.a3 });
            });
```

Is it not possible to create a table that has no primary key and only foreign keys?

Comment: No - EF needs a primary key - and frankly, it's recommend best practice anyway to **always** have a PK for any "serious" table ...

Comment: Surely you must have some way to uniquely identify `OnlyFKs` records. The fields you use for that identification can be defined as a composite primary key. In that sense, a primary key isn't required, as in a singular primary key field just created for that purpose, aka a *surrogate key*. But you *have to* give EF a primary key for identification which may as well be a composite PK.

Comment: You really want to use a `double` as a key? ???

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a primary key. If you don't want to have a single ID column, but create something like a join table, you can create a composite key made of a1, a2, a3 and b.

> Entity Framework Core supports composite keys - primary key values
>   generated from two or more fields in the database. However, unlike in
>   previous versions of Entity Framework, you cannot use the Key
>   attribute to define composite keys. This can only be done via the
>   Fluent API.

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/key-attribute#composite-keys